# Passing information from an Activity to an Intent and back using Extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I have an activity, which launches an Intent with some Extra information.

```
    intent.putExtra("DATABUNDLE", createEmptyLocationBundle());
    startActivity(intent);
```

The `createEmptyLocationBundle()` just returns a Bundle object with some data in it.

From within the launched Intent, I can get the information no problem.

I can modify the bundle's information from within my Intent, also no problem.

But how do I then **send back** the modified Bundle to the originating activity?

Thanks.

Comment: By doing the exact same thing you have done before, or using `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

In main activity override method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Do something here
        }
}
```

Then also in main activity start intent using this method:

```
startActivityForResult(intent.putExtra("DATABUNDLE", createEmptyLocationBundle()), 0);
```

In launched activity pass back data using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like this. You have to call below to start Activity

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

And override `onActivityResult` method for result.

In target activity

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("key",data);
setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
finish();
```